# Parse Values in TableViewCell not updating

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Very big thanks in advance to anyone who can help me, very much appreciated!

I am building a dating app and I am trying to have my matches load in a table after a parse query.  The expected result is that the table view contains the match image and the match ID.  Right now I have code for that working perfectly below.

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class MyListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate {

var images = [UIImage]()
var userIds = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tView: UITableView!

@IBAction func toSwiperButton(_ sender: Any) {


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToSwiper", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFUser.query()

    query?.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: PFUser.current()?["accepted"] 
 as! [String])

    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in

        if let users = objects {

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    let imageFile = user["photo"] as! PFFile

                    imageFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in

                        if let imageData = data {

                            self.images.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)

                            self.userIds.append(user.objectId!)

                            self.tView.reloadData()


                        }

                    })
                }

            }

        }

    })
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {

return images.count
}

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PDPLIstViewTableViewCell

cell.Image.image = images[indexPath.row]

cell.id.text = userIds[indexPath.row]

return cell


}





}
```

The problem arises when I try to include two additional labels onto the table view for "name" and for "age" - I cant seem to figure the correct way to call them in the query in Parse along with the working photo query.

The result I want is for every cell in the table to have an image (code is working) Id (code is working) Name (code not working) and age (code not working)

By "not working" what I mean is I get a ton of errors when I try o create the variable for age from the parse data so I can pass it into the array so that my tableview can display the text next to the image.

Here is what I have been using for non working code on the "Age" label, I believe the error is where I am trying to pull the name/age using "= data" and I have to use a different term?

```
import UIKit
import Parse


class MyListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate {

var images = [UIImage]()
var userIds = [String]()
var name = [String]()
var age = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tView: UITableView!

@IBAction func toSwiperButton(_ sender: Any) {


    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToSwiper", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let query = PFUser.query()

    query?.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: PFUser.current()?["accepted"] 
    as! [String])

    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects, error) in


        if let users = objects {

            for object in users {

                if let user = object as? PFUser {

                    let ageFile = user["age"] as! PFFile

                    ageFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in

                        if let ageData = data {

                           self.age.append(UILabel(data: ageData)!)
                        }

                    let imageFile = user["photo"] as! PFFile

                    imageFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in

                        if let imageData = data {

                            self.images.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)

                            self.userIds.append(user.objectId!)

                            self.age.append(String(data: ageFile))

                            self.tView.reloadData()


                        }

                    })
                }

            }

        }

    })
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {

    return images.count
}

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: 
indexPath) as! PDPLIstViewTableViewCell

    cell.image.image = images[indexPath.row]

    cell.id.text = userIds[indexPath.row]

    cell.name.text = name[indexPath.row]

    cell.age.text = age[indexPath.row]

    return cell


}





}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reloading the tableview in the loop (a lot), also you do not reload when ageData is complete. Try reloading the tableview once, once the query is done. In the:

```
internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let ageFile = age[indexPath.row] as? PFFile else { return }

    ageFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in

        if let ageData = data {

             cell.age.text = ageData
        }
}
```

Comment: This was a huge help in pointing me in the right direction, I ended up at a bit of a different place, but thank you so much for pointing the right way.  Very appreciative of the response!

Comment: Sure, no problem. If the answer is correct, you can this as answer as correct. Otherwise it might be good to answer you own question for future users.

Comment: I did up vote it as correct but the system says my votes are not displayed because I dont have enough reputation points whomp whomp...

Comment: It's not about the vote, but about selecting the right answer for your question (green vink).